# JavaScript - How to get 1900/01/01 in UTC+0?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have seen that `Date.UTC()` returns the number of milliseconds in a `Date` object since **January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, universal time**.

If I do `new Date(Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1)).toString()` I get

> Sun Dec 31 1899 23:45:16 GMT-0014 (hora estándar de Europa central)

Why?

Test here:

```js
const date = new Date(1900, 0, 1);
console.log(date.toString())

console.log("==========================");

const date2 = new Date(Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1));
console.log(date2.toString())
```

Comment: JavaScript dates are always in your local timezone. If you want the string representation, use [Date.toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString).

Comment: @cmbuckley I think the OP's more concerned that the date is 14m off, which doesn't sound like a timezone offset. For reference, I correctly get `Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)` and `Sun Dec 31 1899 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`. Next step: see if Europe had weird time zones back in 1900 that tzfiles know about

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris?year=1900 confirms that Europe had a weird 9m21s offset from UTC back in 1900. That's not the same offset you have, but that page is Western European Time. I'm convinced searching for Central European Time will give you the answer. Standardized time zones weren't really universal back then.

Comment: And I get "Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"

Comment: If you have excessive spare time, `zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin` will show you the weird time zone changes Berlin (for example) went through prior to 1916

Comment: Voting to close since the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @cmbuckley—that comment is misleading. Date instances are UTC, it's their various methods (*get*, *set*, *toString*, etc.) that are based on "local" (i.e. system) settings.

Comment: @barrycarter—that offset isn't weird. Prior to about 1900, each significant city had an offset based on the local mean solar noon (effectively longitude). Offsets in hours and minutes were the norm. High speed travel (trains and later aircraft) made that situation very difficult for timetables, so a global system of timezones based on hour and half–hour offsets roughly based on longitude was introduced and persists to this day.

Comment: @RobG Thanks. I actually got there myself per the comments above :) I know Saudi Arabia used solar time right into the 1980s or so I think. They still use it for religious purposes, but have adopted a more normal civil time zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString()` will return tour local time based on OS configuration.
If you want UTC then use `toUTCString()`

```js
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1)).toString())
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1)).toUTCString())
```